# How to get the html code of the page opened in a WebBrowser in the correct encoding?

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, webbrowser-control

I try to get the Html code of the page open in "webBrowser".

```
public string GetHTMLCodPage()
{
    string htmlCodPage;
    htmlCodPage = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

    return htmlCodPage;
}
```

I get the code (showing the code snippet)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>���������, ����������� �����, ����������� �����, ����������� ������ - C# - ����������</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2385183.html" />

    <base href="http://www.cyberforum.ru/" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />

<meta name="keywords" content="C#, ���������, ����������� �����, ����������� �����, ����������� ������" />
<meta name="description" content="������: ���������, ����������� �����, ����������� �����, ����������� ������ C# �����" />
```

**Question**
How to get the html code of the page opened in the WebBrowser in the correct encoding?

Answer (score 2):

The (let's call it) standard way is to read the [WebBrowser.DocumentStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream) instead of the transcoded [DocumentText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext).

Then, use the internal encoding (the page `Content-Type charset`), provided by the [WebBrowser.Document.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.encoding) property and use this encoding to read the Stream.

Use this code when the `WebBrowser.Document` is loaded completely, subscribing to the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) event and waiting until the [WebBrowser1.ReadyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate) = [WebBrowserReadyState.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate).

In the sample code, the encoded text is sent to a TextBox control.
It's just an example. Do whatever you want with it. But be aware that the `DocumentCompleted` event may be raised multiple times.

```
//Somewhere...
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.cyberforum.ru/");


private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

    string decodedText = string.Empty;
    var htmlStream = webBrowser1.DocumentStream;
    var pageEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(webBrowser1.Document.Encoding);

    using (StreamReader destReader = new StreamReader(htmlStream, pageEncoding)) {
        decodedText = destReader.ReadToEnd();
    };
    textBox1.Text = decodedText;
}
```

Now the text of the page content is using the correct encoding:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="форум программистов, компьютерный форум, киберфорум,(...)" />
<meta name="description" content="КиберФорум - форум программистов (...)" />
```